# Kendo Ui nested JSON Parse

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-grid

I having issues in pushing sharepoint nested json objects to "results" so the data can be used in the Kendo Grid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
parse: function (data) {
    console.log(data.d.results.length);
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            var items = data.d.results[i];
            for (var x = 0; x < item.AttachmentFiles.results.length; x++) {
            var attachment = {
                Attachments: item.AttachmentFiles.results[x].FileName
        };

        results.push(attachment);
    }
    return data.d.results && results;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as a work around I was able to place the attachmentfiles in a function for the column template.

```
Title: "AttachmentFiles", template: function (d) {

                        var attachments = [];

                        for (var x = 0; x < d.AttachmentFiles.results.length; x++) {

                            console.log(d.AttachmentFiles.results[x].FileName);

                            attachments.push(d.AttachmentFiles.results[x].FileName);


                        }
                         return attachments;
                    }
```